# Why is this simple linked list program giving segmentation fault?

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am simply trying to create a linked list of characters. Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
    char data;
    struct node *next;
};

void push(struct node** head,char ndata)
{
    struct node* temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data=ndata;
    temp->next=(*head);
    *head=temp;
}

void display(struct node* head)
{
    struct node* temp=head;

    while(temp)
    {
        printf("%c ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }   
}

int main()
{
    struct node* head;
    int a=1;
    push(&head,'a');
    push(&head,'b');
    push(&head,'c');
    push(&head,'b');
    push(&head,'a');

    display(head);  
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I am using push() function which inserts the values at head. And then using display() method to display the values in the list. When I execute the program,
it says "program10.exe has stopped working". 
I don't understand what the problem is. Can anyone help?

Comment: `sizeof(node)` ? without a `typedef`? how??

Comment: I am using Dev-CPP compiler. It automatically "attaches" typedef.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't initialize `head` so it's not null but has a garbage value, so it doesn't stop the loop in the `display` function, and tries to dereference garbage there.

This:

```
struct node* head;
```

Should be:

```
struct node* head = NULL;
```

Comment: Damn. How did I miss that? Thanks mate.